# Set Control Styles to ThemeResource Values Programmatically In Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm adding some controls dynamically in my Windows Phone 8.1 application. In the XAML, you can set various styles to the current theme's style just as I set the foreground attribute of this TextBlock control in the following example.

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
```

I want to be able to do the same thing in the code behind, but have not yet been able to determine how to do this. I create the TextBlock programmatically as follows.

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock() {
    Text = "Hello World",
    Foreground = // Need to get phone accent brush from theme
};
```

I've seen examples where different theme values are stored as follows, but this Dictionary doesn't seem to contain any keys when I checked for theme resources.

```
SolidColorBrush phoneAccent = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does Rob's answer work when you change the theme during run-time?

Comment: Yes, it does work when the theme changes during run-time.

Comment: Thanks @tribute2ro, that's an interesting thing to know. I mostly work with Windows applications, so if one-time brush assignment in the code works the same as ThemeResource binding in XAML, there must be a significant difference in themes handling between Win 8.1 and WP 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it from PhoneAccentBrush not PhoneAccentColor:

```
Brush accentBrush = Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as Brush;
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "Hello World",
    Foreground = accentBrush 
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was just accessing the wrong Resources dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic .net:

```
.Foreground = CType(Resources.Item("PhoneAccentBrush"), Brush)
```